# How to save file by specific date and time in php (Cakephp)?

Tags: php, cakephp, batch-processing

I'm currently developing POS System.

> In this system, I've to save daily report (CSV file on project folder)
>   at 5:30 pm of everyday without clicking button, without opening the
>   website.

But I don't know how to do this automatic (batch) processing.

As for now I was using cakephp but if php code as sample it's ok for me now.

Please help me. NO code includes because I don't know how to code this process. Thanks you for helping. I already searched in google and I didn't understand the explanation.

Comment: Most likely you want to check `cron` it will run scripts at specific times as long as system is running

Comment: cron? Can you explain me more please. I'm a beginner. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Cron(similar to scheduler task for windows) can run automated tasks 
using command `crontab -e` you can edit scheduled tasks, at end of file you write

```
30 17 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script/execute.php > /home/<user>/crontab-output
```

You need to edit path to script and part of  with your username on system as output of script would be printed to `crontab-output` file

This should execute script at 5pm and 30minutes every day

Some explanation for cron can be found [here](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)